# How to set access color property of the parent and set it to svg icon in react

Tags: reactjs, svg

How can I have my svg icon component's color change dependent on the parent's `color` property?

```
const Icon= ({
  className: overriddenClasses,
  style: overriddenStyles,
  size = defaultSize,
  color = 'black',
}) => (
  <svg
    viewBox='0 0 33 32'
    style={{
      ...overriddenStyles,
      width: size,
      height: size,
      flexShrink: '0',
    }}
    className={overriddenClasses}
  >
    <path
      fill={color}
      d='M29.799 8.661c-0....'
    />
  </svg>
);
```

presently, I'm passing color as a separate prop from the parent.

Comment: how is your icon included on the page?

Comment: I'm using it right now as a react component.

Comment: OK, so now you've added the code, whatever colour the parent is, pass that as a property to your icon.

Comment: How can I obtain the parent colour, though, and provide it to the icon? For instance, if I set the parent's attribute to `color:'green'`, which means that all of the text within is green, I want the icon colour to change at the same time.

Comment: set the parent colour to whatever you want, then you know what it is.

Comment: How can I use js to retrieve the parent's color property?, here I'm passing color manually, how can I set icon color automatically based on the parent's property..?

Comment: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-pass-props-to-component/